# Associating a dojoAttachpoint to a div created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I want to create a div dynamically and want to attach a dojoAttachpoint. How can i do so?

Following code is used to add a div dynamically, but i want to attach a dojoAttachpoint too

```
var txt = dojo.create("div", {
    id: "alert",
    role: "alert",
    'class': "contenthide",
    innerHTML: msg
}, dojo.body());
```

Comment: I believe you are still confused what a dojoAttachPoint is...  Maybe you don't mean a dojoAttachPoint at all but actually something else.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you shouldn't need to. The `dojoAttachPoint`'s purpose to allow you to get an unambigious handle onto the `div` within your dijit when it's declared declaratively (particularly important if you are creating more than one of your dijit on the same page).

However, because you are creating the `div` dynamically, you already have the handle - in your case, the variable `txt`. This will perform the same function. If you need it to become a property of your dijit, just create one:

```
this._myDivsPseudoAttachPoint = txt;
```

Answer (score 0):

As i know, you can use dojoAttachPoint only in **widget template string** [dojo-what-is-a-widget](http://dojocampus.org/content/2008/04/20/what-is-a-_widget/)

[dojoAttachPoint, dojoAttachEvent, waiRole, waiState attributes documentation](http://www.cdr2.com/dojo/dojo-release-1.4.0/docs/dijit/_Templated.html#dijit-templated)