# user friendly urls in j2ee application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, struts

I want to develop a forum application using jsp, servlets.Now i want to have user friendly url to each post eg

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509365/associating-a-dojoattachpoint-to-a-div-create-dynamicallycaly
```

and I dont want to use something like that

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/post=1234
```

How can i have such user friendly urls.

Comment: How is the `struts` tag relevant? "Using Struts" is not equal to "Using JSP/Servlet".

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for  [Representational State Transfer (REST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a technology named **URL Rewrite**, usually people **put a nginx in front of tomcat**, so the nginx get the request:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509365/associating-a-dojoattachpoint-to-a-div-create-dynamicallycaly`
```

and nginx forward a url to tomcat which tomcat can understand:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions?id=5509365`

---

or if you want **pure java solution**, then take a look at:

> `http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/`

Comment: What if I have an app with hard coded URLs in JSPs and I want to change it? How would I change all those URLs, does nginx take care of HTML preprocessing?